# Showing that $\mathbb{P}[X\geq a]\leq \exp[-ta]\mathbb{E}[\exp[tX]]$

Tags: probability, measure-theory

The problem is to show that $\mathbb{P}[X\geq a]\leq \exp[-ta]\mathbb{E}(\exp[tX])$ given $\exp(tX)<\infty$ for $t\in \mathbb{R}$ where $X$ is a random variable.

Then to show that $\mathbb{P}[X\geq a]\leq \inf\limits_{t\in\mathbb{R}} \exp[-ta]\mathbb{E}(\exp[tX])$. But I imagine this shouldn't be too difficult after the first part.

I tried to use Jensen's inequality.

$\psi(X)=\exp(tX)$ is a convex function so

$\psi(\mathbb E (X)) \leq\mathbb  E (\psi (X)) \equiv\mathbb E( \exp[tX])$

So I am left with $\mathbb P [X\geq a]\exp[ta]$ on the LHS which seems to have no relation to $\exp(\mathbb E[tX])$ i.e. $\psi(\mathbb E(tX))$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: The inequality is equivalent to showing that:
$$
{\rm E}\left[1_{\{X\geq a\}}e^{ta}\right]\leq {\rm E}\left[e^{tX}\right].
$$